# Passing parameters form link_to_action to controller in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I am working with laravel 4 and I have to create links that invoke the methods of the controller passing data to the controller.

I chose to use the `link_to_action`, but failed to work.

This is the my HTML code:

```
{{link_to_action('ResearchController@access_data', 'Dati Accesso', array('dati'=>'id'), array('class' => 'btn btn-default'));}}
```

and I want connect this link to the access_data method in my `ResearchController` and I want to pass some parameters present in `array('dati'=>'id')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('ResearchController@access_data', 'Dati Accesso' , array('dati'=>'id', 'class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
```